# Data cleaning: agreggate similar fields in one

Tags: r, data-cleaning

how can I group elements of a variable by common patterns.  for example I have a database in which there is a field called company role and I would like to be able to group the common roles into one.

```
employee <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
Rol      <- c(" accounting assistant", "accou assist", "account.assistant", 
              "healt aux", "auxiliary in healt")
DF <- data.frame(employee, Rol)
```

I would like to transform it into something like this

| Employeee | ROL |
| --- | --- |
| A | accounting assistant |
| B | accounting assistant |
| C | accounting assistant |
| D | Healt auxiliary |
| E | Healt auxiliary |

At the moment i'm manually indentifying the patterns but as the data grows the task becomes more complex, i'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: For the `Healt auxiliary`, do you have a key/value pair

Comment: Try `cbind(DF, cl=cutree(hclust(as.dist(adist(tolower(DF$Rol)))), h=16))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
# your dataframe
employee <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
Rol      <- c(" accounting assistant", "accou assist", "account.assistant", 
              "healt aux", "auxiliary in healt")
DF <- data.frame(employee, Rol)

# save the terms you want to unify in vectors
vector_accounting <- c(" accounting assistant", "accou assist", "account.assistant")
vector_healt <- c("healt aux", "auxiliary in healt")

# apply changes with %in%
DF1 <- DF %>% 
  mutate(Rol = case_when(Rol %in% vector_accounting ~ "accounting assistent",
                         Rol %in% vector_healt ~ "Heat auxiliary"))
```

[image]

Comment: I think OP doesn't want this. Some fuzzy kinda join as far as I can understand

Comment: Ok. I see. Thanks.